# Restangular: can I do Restangular.one('resource').get('123') to achieve GET /resource/123?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Because earlier in my service I did: `var somethingResource = Restangular.one('somethings')` and in my getSomethings method I wanted to do `somethingResource.getList()` and in my getSomethingById methid I wanted to do 'somethingResource.get('123')' to achieve GET /somethings/123

Comment: why the downvote? at least add a comment explaining

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it works.  Doing Restangular.one('resource').get('123') works to achieve GET /resource/123